Y~Geometric(p) then why does the CDF of Y have the floor function?
Here is the screenshot from my textbook, Hossein Pishro-Nik
Here, I have calculated the CDF of Y to be 1 - q^y. But the next step involved y being a floor function. I am not sure why that is the case since y is a geometric variable and would  always be an integer.

You should use MathJax for essential parts of you question instead of pictures.

For an integer valued random variable  $Y$, the inequality $Y \le y$ holds if and only if $Y \le \lfloor y \rfloor$. The Formula $P(Y \le y)=1-(1-p)^{n}$ has been derived only for integer values of $n$, so you have to use $P(Y \le \lfloor y \rfloor)$ to complete the calculation.
